# How to convert string table name in table linq?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have this code:

```
//Convert senderObject to MenuItem
MenuItem menuSelec = (MenuItem)sender;
//Obtain the selected table name
String nombreTabla = menuSelec.Header.ToString();
```

In variable `nombreTabla` I have the string name of the Table that I want to convert to a Table element to assign in a `DataContext` in this way:

```
NorthwindDataContext northWind = new NorthwindDataContext();
dataGrid1.DataContext = northWind.Employees.ToList();
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use Reflection to achieve that:

```
dataGrad1.DataContext = northWind.GetType().GetProperty(nombreTabla).GetValue(northWind, null);
```

This code will take your context class type, search for a property using your table name and return its value.

Comment: Thanks MarcinJuraszed, but I test your sample and this error appears: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.Could you tell me what is that?

Comment: It means you don't have a property with name equal to nombreTabla value.